# Envió masivo al servidor

Tags: jquery, laravel

Estoy cargando un archivo excel que posteriormente convierto en un datatable, ese datatable tengo que validarlo de manera automática, una vez que lo valide deberé enmarcar en rojo la celda del datatable que tiene el error, tendré que poder corregir la celda con el error y una vez que todo esté listo podré guardar en la base de datos.

EL problema radica en la validación masiva después de subir el excel y convertirlo en datatable. Cada campo del datatable debo validarlo y mostrar si hay error, **cuando hago la validación en algunas ocasiones no en todas me da un error 500 (Error interno de servidor)**, lo curioso del caso es que si uso el inspector de código me muestra donde hubo la falla, me da la opción de intentar enviar el dato nuevamente y cuando lo hago funciona perfectamente. El error es solo cuando hace la validación automática. Cabe mencionar que la validación la hago usando Validator de Laravel y ajax para enviar la información al servidor.

**Muestro funcion que valida hecha en Jquery**

```
//Esta función valida de manera automática los campos del datatble cuando se carga el excel
function validar($td)
{
    var $this = $td;
    var $id = $this.attr("id");
    var $text = $this.text().toString();



        /*Se envía un ajax con el id y con el valor del input para validarlo en Laravel */
    $.ajax
        ({
            url: 'editable',
            type: 'get',
            async:'true',
            data: {'id': $id, 'value': $text},
            dataType: 'json'

        }).done(function (data) {
    var bandera=data.bandera;

    /*Si la bandera es 0 significa que lo agarra la validacion*/
    if(bandera==0)
    {

        $.each(data.error, function ($index, $contenido) {

            $this.attr("style","border: solid #ff1b08;");

            $this.tooltip({
                content:" "+$contenido
            });




        });

    }
```

El `tooltip` es porque cuando obtego el error ya desmaterealizado del array lo muestro en un `tooltip` en el campo del `datatable` donde está el problema. Fíjate que también pinto un recuadro de color rojo.

**Muestro ahora la función en php que hace la validación. Recuerde que uso Validator de Laravel**

```
public function editable(Request $request)
{
    if($request->ajax())
    {
        $id=$request->id;

    switch ($id) {
       case "albaran":
            $data = $request->all();
            $rules = array(
                'value' => 'required|max:10|string'
            );
            $messages = array(
                'value.required' => 'El campo no puede ser blanco',
                'value.max' => 'El valor maximo es 10 caracteres',
                'value.string' => 'El valor debe ser caracteres'
            );
            $v = Validator::make($data, $rules, $messages);
            if ($v->fails()) {
                return response()->json([
                    'error' => $v->errors(),
                    'bandera'=>0

                ]);
            } else {
                return response()->json([
                    'bandera' =>1

                ]);
            }
            break;


        case "destinatario":
            $data = $request->all();
            $rules = array(
                'value' => 'required|max:28|string'
            );
            $messages = array(
                'value.required' => 'El campo no puede ser blanco',
                'value.max' => 'El valor maximo es 28 caracteres',
                'value.string' => 'El valor debe ser caracteres'
            );
            $v = Validator::make($data, $rules, $messages);
            if ($v->fails()) {
                return response()->json([
                    'error' => $v->errors(),
                    'bandera'=>0

                ]);
            } else {
                return response()->json([
                    'bandera' =>1

                ]);
            }
            break;

        case "direccion":
            $data = $request->all();
            $rules = array(
                'value' => 'required|max:250|string'
            );
            $messages = array(
                'value.required' => 'El campo no puede ser blanco',
                'value.max' => 'El valor maximo es 250 caracteres',
                'value.string' => 'El valor debe ser caracteres'
            );
            $v = Validator::make($data, $rules, $messages);
            if ($v->fails()) {
                return response()->json([
                    'error' => $v->errors(),
                    'bandera'=>0

                ]);
            } else {
                return response()->json([
                    'bandera' =>1

                ]);
            }
            break;

        case "poblacion":
            $data = $request->all();
            $rules = array(
                'value' => 'max:10|string'
            );
            $messages = array(
                'value.max' => 'El valor maximo es 10 caracteres',
                'value.string' => 'El valor debe ser caracteres'
            );
            $v = Validator::make($data, $rules, $messages);
            if ($v->fails()) {
                return response()->json([
                    'error' => $v->errors(),
                    'bandera'=>0

                ]);
            } else {
                return response()->json([
                    'bandera' =>1

                ]);
            }
            break;

        case "cp":
            $data = $request->all();
            $rules = array(
                'value' => 'required|max:5|min:5|string'
            );
            $messages = array(
                'value.required' => 'El campo no puede ser blanco',
                'value.max' => 'El valor maximo es 5 caracteres',
                'value.min' => 'Debe colocar minimo 5 caracteres',
                'value.string' => 'El valor debe ser caracteres'
            );
            $v = Validator::make($data, $rules, $messages);
            if ($v->fails()) {
                return response()->json([
                    'error' => $v->errors(),
                    'bandera'=>0

                ]);
            } else {
                return response()->json([
                    'bandera' =>1

                ]);
            }
            break;

        case "provincia":
            $data = $request->all();
            $rules = array(
                'value' => 'required|max:20|string'
            );
            $messages = array(
                'value.required' => 'El campo no puede ser blanco',
                'value.max' => 'El valor maximo es 20 caracteres',
                'value.string' => 'El valor debe ser caracteres'
            );
            $v = Validator::make($data, $rules, $messages);
            if ($v->fails()) {
                return response()->json([
                    'error' => $v->errors(),
                    'bandera'=>0

                ]);
            } else {
                return response()->json([
                    'bandera' =>1

                ]);
            }
            break;

        case "telefono":
            $data = $request->all();
            $rules = array(
                'value' => 'required|max:10|string'
            );
            $messages = array(
                'value.required' => 'El campo no puede ser blanco',
                'value.max' => 'El valor maximo es 10 caracteres',
                'value.string' => 'El valor debe ser caracteres'
            );
            $v = Validator::make($data, $rules, $messages);
            if ($v->fails()) {
                return response()->json([
                    'error' => $v->errors(),
                    'bandera'=>0

                ]);
            } else {
                return response()->json([
                    'bandera' =>1

                ]);
            }
            break;

        case "observaciones":
            $data = $request->all();
            $rules = array(
                'value' => 'max:500|string'
            );
            $messages = array(
                'value.max' => 'El valor maximo es 500 caracteres',
                'value.string' => 'El valor debe ser caracteres'
            );
            $v = Validator::make($data, $rules, $messages);
            if ($v->fails()) {
                return response()->json([
                    'error' => $v->errors(),
                    'bandera'=>0

                ]);
            } else {
                return response()->json([
                    'bandera' =>1

                ]);
            }
            break;

        case "fecha":
            $data = $request->all();
            $rules = array(
                'value' => 'required|date_format:d/m/Y H:i'
            );
            $messages = array(
                'value.required' => 'El campo no puede ser blanco',
                'value.date_format' => 'El campo debe tener un formato de fecha valido: DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM'
            );
            $v = Validator::make($data, $rules, $messages);
            if ($v->fails()) {
                return response()->json([
                    'error' => $v->errors(),
                    'bandera'=>0

                ]);
            } else {
                return response()->json([
                    'bandera' =>1

                ]);
            }
            break;


    }
    }

}
```

Cuando cargo el excel en el formulario, yo envío el formulario por ajax usando la función:

```
$("#formularioajax").on("submit", function (e){}
```

Ya que tengo validaciones de campos (que el campo donde se adjunta el excel no sea blanco por ejemplo) y donde disparo el proceso de carga de excel en Laravel.

Cuando todo ha funcionado entonces fabrico el datatable y luego llamo a la validación automática. Como les he dicho eso lo hago celda por celda y lo hago así:

```
 $("td,.edit").each(function()
  {
    validar($(this));
  });
```

Recuerde que la función `validar` está más arriba.

Hay veces cuando se ejecuta este paso me da error 500 y no sé como tratarlo, no se me ocurre una mejor forma de validar los campos para que no me de ese error 500.

Comment: Busca el error.log de apache (si es que usas apache) para ver que está pasando. El error está causado en el entorno de PHP y por tanto, en el lado del servidor, debes buscar ahí. Si nos pegas el trozo del log en donde sale el error, podremos ayudarte.

Comment: He buscado en los Log....y en verdad que no hay nada relacionado con la ejecución que estoy haciendo

Comment: ¿cuántos datos son enviados en promedio? No veo muy eficiente el enviar un dato a la vez por ajax para que sea validado (si es que entiendo bien lo que intentas hacer). Por favor agrega el código completo que carga el archivo de Excel y su procesamiento.

Comment: Son unos 30 aproximadamente son muy pocos.....me llama la atención lo que dices...como se puediera hacer entonces para validar cada campo o cada celda del datatable y luego asignarle los errores a cada una?  fijate que lo haga uno en uno porque tengo que validar todos los registros.

Comment: Pues por ejemplo, en lugar de lanzar la llamada ajax en cada vuelta de bucle, guarda los datos en un array para mandarlo de una sola vez. En tu caso particular el bucle es el $("td,.edit").each(function() o si realmente el problema es la carga, prueba con un delay entre envío y envío